# Google Sheets query - Multiple "where" conditions with "group by" and "order by"

Tags: google-sheets-query

I'm trying to use multiple `where` conditions (2 conditions) with 'group by' and 'order by' statements inside a Google Sheets Query formula.

```
query(Sites!A:D,"select A,C,sum(D) 
    where B contains 'Google' 
    and sum(D) > 100 
    group by A,C 
    Order by sum(D) desc label sum(D) 'Total Impressions'")
```

Above is the formula I tried, but it gives me an error with #VALUE!

Is it an issue with the order of statements?

Answer (score 2):

[Aggregation functions can be used in select, order by, label, format clauses. They cannot appear in where, group by, pivot, limit, offset, or options clauses.](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#operators)

Answer (score 1):

Add a second where should work

```
query(Sites!A:D,"select A,C,sum(D) 
    where B contains 'Google' 
    and where sum(D) > 100 
    group by A,C 
    order by sum(D) desc label sum(D) 'Total Impressions'")
```